# Distributing scikit-learn with Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn

So I have been working on distributing and parallelizing the execution of different ML algorithms with different parameter combinations. I am performing experiments on a cluster environment and I want to exploit as much as possible all the available resources.
More info on: [How are tasks distributed within a Spark cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202084/how-are-tasks-distributed-within-a-spark-cluster)

My input consists of the list of the algorithms and parameters in JSON format. Based on this scenario, I have 2 approaches:

1. For each ML algorithm I have, I create a SparkGridSearch object (from the [official integration](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn)) and put it into a list. Then, I fire the execution of these grid search objects on different threads, as follows:

   ```
   ...
   for experiment in experiments:
       # experiment contains the algorithm and its list of parameters
       gridSearchCV = SparkGridSearchCV(spark_context, experiment[0], experiment[1], scoring=experiment[2], cv=experiment[3])
       experiment_thread = Thread(target=run_experiment, args=(bcast_dataframe, gridSearchCV))
       experiment_thread.start()
   ```

Input:

```
experiments_dict = {
    'Decision Tree': {'num_folds': 2, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'criterion': ['entropy'], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Naive Bayes': {'num_folds': 2, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {}},
    'Random Forests': {'num_folds': 2, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'n_estimators': [5, 7]}},
    'Random Forests_2': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'bootstrap': [True, False], 'criterion': ['entropy'], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Decision Tree_2': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [2, 3, None], 'max_depth': [None], 'class_weight': ['balanced', None]}},
    ...
}
```

2. I have also created a list in which each element is one algorithm with one parameter combination. Therefore, the size of this list is much bigger than in the previous approach since each combination is one element of the list. In this case, I simply use `spark.parallelize` on this list and map it to the function in which I run each ML algorithm:

   ```
   def run_experiment(dataframe, experiment):
      ...
      model = estimator.fit(train_data, train_target)

      predicted = model.predict(test_data)

      score = accuracy_score(predicted, expected)
      return [model, score]


   def main(): 
     ...
     bcast_dataset = spark_context.broadcast(df)

     experimentsRDD = spark_context.parallelize(experiments_dict)

     print experimentsRDD.map(lambda experiment: run_experiment(bcast_dataset, experiment)).collect()

     bcast_dataset.unpersist()
   ```

Input:

```
experiments_dict = {
    'Decision Tree': {'num_folds': 2, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'criterion': ['entropy'], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Naive Bayes': {'num_folds': 2, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {}},
    'Random Forests': {'num_folds': 2, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'n_estimators': [5]}},
    'Random Forests_1_2': {'num_folds': 2, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'n_estimators': [7]}},
    'Random Forests_2': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'bootstrap': [True, False], 'criterion': ['entropy'], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Random Forests_2_1': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'bootstrap': [False], 'criterion': ['entropy'], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Decision Tree_2': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [2], 'max_depth': [None], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Decision Tree_2_1': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [3], 'max_depth': [None], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Decision Tree_2_2': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [None], 'max_depth': [None], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}},
    'Decision Tree_2_3': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [2], 'max_depth': [None], 'class_weight': ['None']}},
    'Decision Tree_2_4': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [3], 'max_depth': [None], 'class_weight': ['None']}},
    'Decision Tree_2_5': {'num_folds': 3, 'evaluation': 'accuracy', 'parameters': {'splitter': ['random'], 'max_leaf_nodes': [None], 'max_depth': [None], 'class_weight': ['None']}},
        ...
}
```

I have performed some experiments and obtained better results with the second approach. However, when changing the number of partitions (equals to the number of experiments, or 2 or 3 times the number of available cores) the execution time is not varying.
I also had a few problems when broadcasting the dataset with Spark in the multithreading approach, but apparently this is a known [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12717).

My questions: these results make sense? Why doesn't the number of partitions influence on the execution time? Am I missing something or is there something I can improve?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your experiment quite well. You are changing the number of partitions on what ? Your experiments seems to be distributed but your data is local. Correct me if I'm mistaken !

Comment: Hi @eliasah Thank you for your comment. Yes, the data is supposed to be local, I am not distributing it, only broadcasting a pandas dataframe. The number of partitions I am changing on this `spark_context.parallelize(experiments_dict)`

Comment: In that case, partitioning wouldn't help. Partitioning is about distributing data /the level of parallelism over data across computing nodes but in your case, you are just distributing learning over local data.

Comment: You can tried to partition by algorithm type but I still believe that your experiments aren't in the order of tens of thousand to benefit from partitioning

Comment: I understand. What I wanted to make sure is that the learning is fairly distributed among the node. Plus, does it make sense that the second approach is faster than the first?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your setup quite well. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127924/apache-spark